# Vim: Add a statement to all the functions in the file

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to add a print statement to all functions in a python script (the programming language shouldn't matter here though) using vim. Basically I want to change this:

```
def func1(a, b):
    pass
```

into this:

```
def func1(a, b):
    print 'in func1'
    pass
```

I was thinking of something like `:g/\vdef (\w+)\(/CMD` , but my vim skills are not yet good enough to come up with `CMD`. Does anyone know what I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use whatever you’ve used to do this job by yourself, prefixed with `:normal!`:

```
g/\vdef\ (\w+)\(/exe "normal!^wywoprint 'in \<C-r>0'"
```

(note: according to the help, you must escape space when using `\v`:

> Use of "\v" means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
>   '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.  "very magic"

. You see, space is not listed here.)

Comment: This worked pretty well, thanks! Is it possible to use the groups from the regular expression in the `exe "..."` expression? Something like `exe "normal!oprint in " + \1` ?

Comment: No because the capture group is lost by the time you arrive at `execute "…"`. ZyX's workaround is to yank the function name and use it with `<C-r>0`. One could use a substitution right from the start, I guess.

Comment: Oh I see. What do you mean by using a substitution right from the start?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative using only one substitution (based on ZyX' pattern).

```
:%s/\v(def\ )(\w+)(\(.*\):)(\n\s*)/\1\2\3\4print "in \2"\4
```

Breakdown:

- `(def\ )` is the first capture group, followed by
- `(\w+)`, the second capture group, the name of the function that we want to re-use, followed by
- `(\(.*\):)`, the third capture group, folowed by
- `(\n\s*)`, the last capture group that we will use to indent the new line correctly.
- `\1\2\3\4` re-prints the whole match because we don't want to change it, then
- `print "in \2"` is the new content that we want, followed by
- `\4` which keeps the `pass` line intact.

There's probably a way to do nested capture groups but I didn't go that far.

Note that you can combine that with `:global`:

```
:g/\v(def\ )(\w+)(\(.*\):)(\n\s*)/s//\1\2\3\4print "in \2"\4
```

The "complex" pattern used for `:g` is reused for `:s` thanks to `//`.

Comment: You are doing strange things with capturing here: `%s/\vdef\ (\w+)\(.*(\n\s*)\zs/print "in \1"\2`. You could’ve used `\0` in place of `\1\2\3\4`. But you don’t need even this since there is `\zs`.

Comment: I had to cut it into pieces because the OP wanted to re-use some parts later. `\1` is useless, `\2` is what matters to the OP, `\3` is also not needed and `\4` is used for indent adjustment. I thought explicitly cutting it out would be a little clearer if a bit verbose.

Comment: There are yours `\2` and `\4` in my regex: they are `\1` and `\2` and exist for the same reasons. Others are insignificant. And I don’t think `\1\2\3\4` with the explanation “re-prints the whole match” is a tiny bit easier then `\0` with just the same explanation in case you want to avoid `\zs`.